# state in mapStateToProps has wrong data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm pretty sure I have some small configuration wrong, because I *did* have this working.  But when I hit my `mapStateToProps` via the react-redux `connect` call, it is getting injected with my reducers.  My setup is:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import BuildsContainer from '../containers/builds-container';
import NavBarContainer from '../containers/nav-bar-container';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);  
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBarContainer />

                <div className="container body-content">

                    <BuildsContainer />

                    <hr />
                    <footer>
                        <p>&copy; 2016</p>
                    </footer>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

nav-bar-container.js:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import NavBar from '../components/nav-bar'
import  { setUsername } from '../actions/actions'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state)  
    return {username: state.username}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = ({ 
    setUsername: setUsername
}) 

const NavBarContainer = connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapDispatchToProps
)(NavBar)

export default NavBarContainer
```

my main reducer, reducer.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import UsernameReducer from './username-reducer'
import BuildsReducer from './builds-reducer'

const BuildWatcherApp = combineReducers({
    UsernameReducer,
    BuildsReducer
})

export default BuildWatcherApp;
```

and my username-reducer.js:

```
const UsernameReducer = (state = '', action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_USERNAME':
            return action.username
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default UsernameReducer;
```

Where I do `console.log(state)` in my `mapStateToProps` call, its showing:

[image]

it seems `state` has my reducers in it.  That doesn't seem right, I was expecting it to have the `username` prop.  If it's worth noting, the `mapDispatchToProps` does seem to have the correct func being passed to it.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: it is right, because `UsernameReducer` used as key `{ UsernameReducer: UsernameReducer }` in `combineReducers`.

Comment: @AlexanderT. what's the appropriate change to make here? Am I right to expect just `username` on the `state` object, and I've wired it up wrong?  Or is this wired up correctly, and I'm misunderstanding how its supposed to work

Comment: @Jonesopolis in order to understand why it happens you need to look at  `combineReducers` function https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js#L102, https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js#L103. you can see that `combineReducers` used keys, in your case you use two keys `UsernameReducer`, `BuildsReducer`, and for this `key` assign reducer function

Comment: I see what you are saying!  The break did happen when I changed the names on the reducer files.  Awesome that fixed it.  Thanks a ton I was beating my head there.  If you want to answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out my problem was with `combineReducers`:

```
const BuildWatcherApp = combineReducers({
   UsernameReducer,
   BuildsReducer
})
```

where my reducer names didn't match the properties on my state.  Changing this to:

```
const BuildWatcherApp = (state = {}, action) => ({
    username: UsernameReducer(state.username, action),
    builds: BuildsReducer(state.builds, action)
})
```

fixed it.

Comment: Or just change the name that you import the reducers as. Cause you export them as default then you can choose whatever name you want like: username and builds.

Comment: that's a smarter answer

Comment: Yep, this is a common problem, which is why I wrote a section in the Redux docs called [Using `combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) to help clarify how that works.  Also, you can you still use `combineReducers`, you just need to supply the key names you want instead of using the object shorthand:  `combineReducers({username : UsernameReducer, builds : BuildsReducer});`